# Luggage at transit

Tags: air-travel, luggage, tax-refunds

I am travelling A -> B -> C. I have purchased a lot of stuff for which I intend to claim a tax refund at airport B, where I will exit Europe. I think I will have to present the items I have bought to claim the tax return but I do not want to take my bag of shopping on-board with me from A to B.

Is it possible for me to reclaim just one of my bags in B, claim the tax return and then re-check while all my other belongings are checked through all the way to C? I do not want to reclaim my other bags until my final destination.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. "Luggage" isn't a verb and I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you try rephrasing your question?

Comment: I wonder if this is an XY question, and the Y is "do I need to physically present my purchased items to get my VAT refunded, or will they take my word on it if the item is in checked baggage?"

Comment: When I claimed VAT refunds I wasn't asked to present the items. I don't think you're normally asked.

Comment: Here is some anecdotal evidence that you _can_ actually claim at checkin at A: https://community.ricksteves.com/travel-forum/italy/vat-refund-with-a-layover - scroll to the very last post. I'd at least try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not short check one bag to a mid-flight stop and check the rest to your destination.  Checked bags always go to the end destination of the flights you are taking.

You can check an additional bag at B, but it will be subject to the original check in rules.  So if you checked the full number/weight allowed at A, then you will pay the excess baggage fee at B, if you don't check your full allotment at A then the bag at B may be free.

Plus you need to get that bag of goodies to B